# Difference between 'at' and 'by' for percentages

Tags: grammar, word-choice, differences, prepositions, percentages

Please confirm the difference between these two sentences:

> Salad is the most popular dish **by** 43%.
>
> Salad is the most popular dish **at** 43%.

Is the meaning of these two sentences same or different? (this sentence came directly from an electronic dictionary. The full text is:

> In America the most popular business lunch is a salad **by** 43% over a meat dish **at** 26%.)

Does it mean that a salad is 43% more popular with a popularity of 69%? Or is the usage of the preposition by simply a mistake in this sentence?

Comment: "Salad is the most popular dish at 43%" sounds more natural _on its own_.  "By" is probably used in the full sentence because a comparison is being made; salad is more popular than meat dishes _by_ the difference between 43% and 26%.

Answer (score 2):

If something is more popular **by** 43%, that means it is 43% more popular than 
the next most popular item (whether absolute or relative is left ambiguous).

If it's more popular **at** 43%, that is what it's percentage is - the next most popular item may be at 42%, for example.

Basically the difference lies in whether or not the percentage given is relative to the next most popular item. I would say that the usage in your example is mistaken - or at least very unclear

Answer (score 0):

While what @Chromane said is correct, it changes a little with context.

In general yes, "**by** 43%" means 43% **more**, and "**at** 43%" means that is the flat percentage.

However, the "at" in the sentence you gave acts like a colon would. Therefore it should be read as:

> Salad is the most popular business lunch in America (presumably in
>   some kind of vote or survey, 43% of people gave this as their answer),
>   and the next most popular is the meat dish, which 26% of people voted
>   for.

I agree that this is not a particularly clear sentence, but the "at" given is not ungrammatical, just made even more confusing by the use of percentages.